# How to set up owncloud on DNS-323 NAS with Alt-F 0.1RC5 firmware installed?

Tags: nas

Installing it via `Packages -> Alt-F -> ownlcloud -> install` worked, but I got an **empty page** accessing `https://mynas:8443/owncloud` (only for testing: `http://mynas:8080/owncloud`) (which forwarded to `.../index.php`).

Comment: Some user tried to install Owncloud 8 (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/alt-f/z8NAVV3CtVA/CH1TXBdHCQAJ), but it does not fully work yet (https://groups.google.com/d/msg/alt-f/z8NAVV3CtVA/2VgLrIh6CgAJ).

Answer (score 0):

In the `Utilities -> View log: error` I found:

```
(mod_fastcgi.c.2695) FastCGI-stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function 
  OC\Session\session_name() in /opt/owncloud/lib/private/session/internal.php on line 20
(mod_fastcgi.c.2695) FastCGI-stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function 
  json_encode() in /opt/owncloud/lib/private/log/owncloud.php on line 86
```

So I read that this means some php extensions are likely not enabled and so this fixed it:

1. activate the php extensions via config file:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/php.ini
   ```

   - replace **all** lines `;extension=...` with `extension=...`, e.g. `extension=json.so`
   - maybe not all extensions are needed, but it worked, so I don't bother

     - an now I found that you should be able to [exactly find out which with this info](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/alt-f/php|sort:relevance/alt-f/z8NAVV3CtVA/goPOzTo5BgAJ)
2. now restart the php server: `services -> network -> lighttpd -> stop/start`

=> should work now :)

---

a little more background info that may be helpful (in case this does not solve the problem in your environment):

- this was the first try to install some cloud service and next I will try to install the probably better *owncloud* fork [*nextcloud*](https://nextcloud.com/compare/) and [this is the outcome](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/397906/141555)
- a very outdated thread from 2012 describes the former install [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20160321204510/http://forum.dsmg600.info/viewtopic.php?pid=46712#p46712)

Comment: I'm not clear: are you presenting an answer or not?  New information is always nice, but it's unusual to provide "more background info that may be helpful" after you've solved the problem.

Comment: That was more a hint in case the environment is different and the solution might slightly differ or may need more steps (actual NAS type - there are similar ones out there, firmware, owncloud/nextcloud versions, installed/ dependent packages)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Some php modules are missing in the default setup. Please look into the webservr error log to see them. Weird that the session stuff is not installed by default because it is used by 90% of the php apps.
Please also use Nextcloud instead of Owncloud because it is fully open source, has more features and is faster and more secure.
And also use https instead of http please. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer-comment (disguised as answer, but I had the same stupid problems at the beginning with the stackoverflow credits). I added the HTTPS solution as default above although for testing I prefer HTTP. Now I am stuck with Nextcloud, but maybe some solutions will be there soon: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/397906/how-to-set-up-nextcloud-on-dns-323-nas-with-alt-f-0-1rc5-firmware-installed